# getting max and min() of a column based on the id in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get the max() and min() date diff on the basis of id column here, if id has multiple same record(ex: id=1) and the diff of date (id=1-id=0) if id doesn't have same record

The query is:

```
SELECT distinct  A.CHANGE_ID,
  c.CHANGE_NUMBER,
  ( SELECT le.ENTRYVALUE FROM listentry le WHERE le.ENTRYID = c.CATEGORY
  ) AS CATEGORY,
  (SELECT distinct n.description FROM nodetable n WHERE n.id = a.state
  )                                            AS workflow_status,
  to_date(A.local_date, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') AS local_date1,
    A.order_by
FROM WORKFLOW_PROCESS A,
change c
where  A.CHANGE_ID  =c.id
ORDER BY A.CHANGE_ID, A.order_by;
```

The result is attached here:

[image: here].

In addition to this, I need a difference of dates with respect to the order_id column.

If order_id is 1 and it has multiple rows, then I need a diff of max and min of local_date.

If unique, need a diff of local_date with respect to (order_id 1 - order_id 0).

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect, as tabular text.

Comment: updated the expected result column **days** above. Thank you!

Comment: is there a column you are not showing for the id of the thing being started/cancelled/put on hold, or do you have 1 such table per thing?

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm still not sure what you mean with "diff of local date with respect to" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've converted your picture to a create statement (which is preferrable for a number of [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)).

```
CREATE TABLE t (id NUMBER, status VARCHAR2(30), local_date DATE, order_by NUMBER);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'Initiate'      , DATE '2018-01-29', 0);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'BOM Specs'     , DATE '2018-01-31', 1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'BOM Specs'     , DATE '2018-01-29', 1);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'Artwork'       , DATE '2018-01-31', 2);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'Artwork'       , DATE '2018-02-07', 2);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'Artwork'       , DATE '2018-02-02', 2);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'First Review'  , DATE '2018-02-05', 3);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'First Review'  , DATE '2018-02-08', 3);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (42,'Second Review' , DATE '2018-02-09', 4);
```

This can be solved with Oracle's [analytical functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056). Takes a while to get used to it, but it certainly is worth it.

To count the number of rows per id and status:

```
 COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status)
```

To get the minimal local_date of those multiple rows:

```
 MIN(local_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status)
```

To get the first row per id (id=0):

```
NTH_VALUE(local_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_by 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
```

And the second one (id=1):

```
NTH_VALUE(local_date,2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_by 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING),
```

To get a feeling for the columns, please check:

```
SELECT id, status, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status) as n,
       MIN(local_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status) as d1,
       MAX(local_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status) as d2,
       NTH_VALUE(local_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_by
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as d3,
       NTH_VALUE(local_date,2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_by 
         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as d4       
  FROM t
 ORDER BY order_by;

ID STATUS        N D1         D2         D3         D4
42 Initiate      1 2018-01-29 2018-01-29 2018-01-29 2018-01-31
42 BOM Specs     2 2018-01-29 2018-01-31 2018-01-29 2018-01-31
42 BOM Specs     2 2018-01-29 2018-01-31 2018-01-29 2018-01-31
42 Artwork       3 2018-01-31 2018-02-07 2018-01-29 2018-01-31
42 Artwork       3 2018-01-31 2018-02-07 2018-01-29 2018-01-31
42 Artwork       3 2018-01-31 2018-02-07 2018-01-29 2018-01-31
42 First Review  2 2018-02-05 2018-02-08 2018-01-29 2018-01-31
42 First Review  2 2018-02-05 2018-02-08 2018-01-29 2018-01-31
42 Second Review 1 2018-02-09 2018-02-09 2018-01-29 2018-01-31
```

Now you can use a `CASE` statement to decide which dates to use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, status,
       CASE WHEN n = 1 THEN d4 - d3 ELSE d2 - d1 END as days,
       order_by
  FROM (
        SELECT id, status, 
               COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status)          as n,
               MIN(local_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status)   as d1,
               MAX(local_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status)   as d2,
               NTH_VALUE(local_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_by 
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as d3,
               NTH_VALUE(local_date,2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_by
                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as d4,
               order_by
          FROM t
       )
 ORDER BY order_by;

ID STATUS         DAYS ORDER_BY
42 Initiate       2    0
42 BOM Specs      2    1
42 Artwork        7    2
42 First Review   3    3
42 Second Review  2    4
```

Theoretically, the nested select is not neccessary, you can also write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, status,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status) = 1
            THEN NTH_VALUE(local_date,2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_by 
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
               - NTH_VALUE(local_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY order_by 
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
            ELSE MAX(local_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status)
               - MIN(local_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id, status)
        END AS days,
       order_by
  FROM t
 ORDER BY order_by;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works but I have a small question. It sounds silly but I am new to this. In this case, if in the table the status count is 1 for all the rows, still it returns the value of row2-row1 itself. Can we make it for all/any rows.